# Invalid config, must be a valid config object - Sencha Touch 2.1

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

When I'm trying to open new Panel after button tap I always get this error:

`Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.Container#factoryItem] Invalid config, must be a valid config object`

Here is the function (Located in custom controller):

```
push : function(navigationView, viewClass) {
    navigationView.push(viewClass);
}
```

And this is how it's called (Located in controller class that extends custom controller):

```
push(this.getNvw_main(), 'First.view.HomePage');
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, view must be instatiated in order to pushed:

```
push : function(navigationView, viewClass) {
    var view = Ext.ClassManager.instantiate(viewClass);
    navigationView.push(view);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your second argument you should probably pass an object with the configs like so: `{xtype:'homepage'}`. That is assuming that your `First.view.Homepage` has an alias `widget.homepage`.